# Duda View Composer y View Creator Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel, laravel-blade

Usando laravel 5.2 tengo dos vistas: `principal.blade`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
         <title>@yield('meta_title', $meta_title)</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

y `secundaria.blade`:

```
@extends('principal')

@section('content')
    <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
@endsection
```

En la principal tengo lo que viene a ser la plantilla y en la secundaria el contenido.

He creado un "CreatorServiceProvider" donde llamo a:

```
public function boot()
{
    view()->creator('principal', 'App\Http\ViewCreators\MetaCreator');
}
```

Y en MetaCreator llamo a :

```
public function create($view)
{
    $view->with([
        'meta_title' => getTheTitle(),
    ]);
}
```

para que cada vez que se cree la vista "principal" tenga unos valores predefinidos (title, description, etc...), estos valores los relleno según la url que tenga en ese momento. Utilizo "ViewCreator" porque quiero tener la posibilidad de sobrescribir estos valores en algún momento de la llamada a la vista si fuese necesario.

El problema no viene a la hora de compartir la variable `meta_title` sino a la hora de sobrescribirla. Con el siguiente código no me sobrescribe la variable`meta_title`:

```
return view('secundaria')->with('meta_title', 'Titulo 2');
```

Solo consigo sobrescribirla si llamo directamente a:

```
return view('principal')->with('meta_title', 'Titulo 2');
```

El problema es que yo en el controlador necesito llamar a la vista secundaria, que extiende de la principal y sobrescribir el valor `meta_title`, y no a la vista principal.

Ahora mismo este problema lo soluciona pasándole a la vista secundario el valor del `meta_title` y esta vista mediante llamando a `@section()` le doy el valor a `meta_title`:

Línea del Controlador donde llamo a la vista secundaria:

```
return view('secundaria', ['meta_title' => 'Titulo 2']);
```

Y la vista secundaria:

```
@extends('principal')

@section('meta_title', $meta_title)

@section('content')
    <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
@endsection
```

Pero me gustaría saber si se puede hacer esto directamente desde el controlador sin tener que pasar por la vista para cambiar el valor:

```
return view('secundaria')->with('meta_title', 'Titulo 2');
```

Se puede hacer así?
Esta bien planteado o hay otra forma mejor de plantearlo?

Gracias.

Comment: En resumen lo que quieres hacer es poder asignar un valor de la vista directamente en el controlador, y no tener que escribir ninguna variable o similar en la vista ¿es correcto?

Comment: Es por que le estas llamando a tu principal de nuevo la variable `$meta_title`

Comment: @Shaz es exactamente lo que quiero hacer

Answer (score 2):

`@yield` recibe dos parametros

principal.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     <title>@yield('titulo', 'Valor por defecto')</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
        @yield('contenido')
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Y ahora en la vista secundaria le pasamos el parámetro:

```
@section('titulo', $titulo )  //

@section('contenido')
@endsection
```

Comment: Gracias, pero eso es básicamente lo que tengo ahora. Igualmente gracias.

Answer (score 0):

A menos que no entienda el problema, no veo la necesidad de un ViewCreator, simplemente puedes usar otro yield para sobreescribir el valor por defecto que le asignes a `meta_title`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
         <title>@yield('meta_title', 'Título por defecto')</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        @yield('content')
    </div>
</body>
```

vista secundaria:

```
@extends('principal')

@section('main_title')
    Mi título personalizado o {{ $nuevo_titulo }}
@endsection

@section('content')
    <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
@endsection
```

Los valores de los títulos pueden ser sustituidos por variables.

Comment: Perdona por la confusión de antes. si quieres elimina esta respuesta ya que voy a modificar la pregunta para que quede todo más claro.